# View email in both parent and nested label

Tags: email, gmail

Is there a way in Gmail to make the emails be viewed in the parent label?
For example, in the following hierarchy:

```
alerts
alerts/service1
alerts/service2
```

The emails that have label 'alerts/service1' will also be shown when viewing emails with 'alerts' label, and ditto for emails with label 'alerts/service2'

I can set my filters to also apply the 'alerts' label, but this will clutter the labeling of all these emails ('alerts' and 'alerts/service1' will both be shown).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly at the moment **there isn't** a way to view the emails in the parent label other than applying the parent label with a filter.

There's no native setting in Gmail and it seems that there are no gmail add-ons that do what you ask.